# How to access name of a specific vertex in graph (python-igraph)

Tags: python, igraph, vertex

I am writing a code in poython and created a graph using python-igraph. Now I want to access vertices names (or maybe other attributes). I know for index it is like this:

```
vs[i].index
```

But I am not sure about the name. When I use the vs[i] itself, it prints the following:

```
igraph.Vertex(<igraph.Graph object at 0x00000000040946D8>, 2, {'name': '3'})
```

So, obviously there is name but apparently I don't know how to access it.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be accessed like the following:

```
graph.vs[i]["name"]
```

It will return the name (or basically the label) of the specific node.

Comment: `graph.vs[i]["name"]` is an alternative form that may be more efficient for large graphs - `graph.vs["name"][i]` first retrieves the name of all the vertices and then extracts the i-th element, while `graph.vs[i]["name"]` just "jumps" to the i-th vertex and then extracts the name.

Comment: @Tamás Any idea how I can access a vertex based on its name? I mean I have a name of a vertex and I want to know what is its index in the adjacency matrix :)

Comment: @ahajib to find index by name -> graph.vs['name'].index('3')

Comment: Not anymore, at least in igraph 0.9.9. graph.vs['name'] fails and graph.vs[i]["name"] fails, with the following error... KeyError: 'Attribute does not exist'